# How do i jest mock a exported module that is used in another module ( typescript )

Tags: typescript, jestjs, aws-serverless

I have 2 modules getPolicy & getBucketPolicyJson  below:

```
import { Policy } from '../types';
import { getBucketPolicyJson } from '../modules/getbucketpolicyjson';

export const getPolicy = async ( resource: string ) => { 
      try {
        const policy = await getBucketPolicyJson( resource ); 
        return policy as Policy;
      } catch (error) {
        return false;
      } 
    }
```

and

```
import { AWSError, S3 } from 'aws-sdk';
import { Policy } from '../types';
export const getBucketPolicyJson = async (resource: string): Promise<Policy> => {
    const s3 = new S3();
    const params = {
      Bucket: resource
    }; 
    return new Promise<Policy>((resolve, reject) => {
      s3.getBucketPolicy(params, async (err, data) => {
        if (err) reject()
        else resolve( JSON.parse(data.Policy!) as Policy );
      });
    });
};
```

Im  putting together some testing for getPolicy

test 1 is that false is returned and im completed that however , i wish to test a policy being returned

```
const policy = await getBucketPolicyJson( resource ); 
return policy as Policy;
```

I don't seem to be able to mock getBucketPolicyJson with a mocked response and have tried numerous ways in mocking.

When ever i run getPolicy, false is always returned

I currently have like below in my test where '../modules/getbucketpolicyjson' is the location of the module im trying to mock getBucketPolicyJson

```
jest.mock('../modules/getbucketpolicyjson');
    const samplePolicy:Policy =  { 'Version': '01', 'Id': '1', 'Statement': [] }   
    jest.fn().mockReturnValue( samplePolicy ) 
    const res = await getPolicy( 'test-buck-policy');
    console.log( "response " + res)
```

I want to understand what im obviously missing and wondered if someone could give me a lead in how i could handle this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I was trying to do something similar, and found it better to make the external objects, dependencies, and use dependency injection to pass them in to the service. The getPolicy would then have the getBucketPolicyJson as a dependency, which can then be mocked in the test for getPolicy, so that you can have data returned, errors or exceptions from getBucketPolicyJson.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Steve thats really helpful and ill give that a go as well as well.
after some more messing i came to a couple of solutions shown below:

to inline mock i mocked with the below using ts-jest/utils but i configure this outside of the quite

```
import { getBucketPolicyJson } from '../modules/getbucketpolicyjson';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';

jest.mock('../modules/getbucketpolicyjson');
const mockedGetBucketPolicyJson = mocked(getBucketPolicyJson, true);
```

Then inline within my test i am able to create a mocked response

```
 const policy = {
      Version: '01',
      Id: '1',
      Statement: []
    };
    mockedGetBucketPolicyJson.mockResolvedValueOnce(policy);
    const res: false | Policy = await getPolicy('test-buck-policy');

    expect(res).toStrictEqual(policy);
```

I was also able to get it working using a **mocks** file just using

```
jest.mock('../modules/getbucketpolicyjson');
```

with out

```
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';
const mockedGetBucketPolicyJson = mocked(getBucketPolicyJson, true);
```

with the response in my __mocks__file named the same as the module i wanted to mock that was also as effective